# Can a model recognize the interactions between variables?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, interaction

I have a data set similar to the following one,

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4 TARGET
1   1  5  3  9      0
2   5  4  3 12      0
3   5  2  2  9      0
4   5  7  1 13      1
5   7  3  2 12      0
6   5  6  6 17      1
7   1  3  4  8      0
8   2  2  7 11      0
9   5  2  6 13      1
10  4  2  1  7      1
```

The above data set can be generated using the following code in R,

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = sample(1:7,10,replace = T)
x2 = sample(1:7,10,replace = T)
x3 = sample(1:7,10,replace = T)
x4 = x1 + x2 + x3
TARGET = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,TARGET)
```

QUESTION:

- I have x1, x2, x3, x4(which is basically the sum(x1,x2,x3)), should I
  remove x1, x2, x3 from the data while modelling?
- Can a model(preferably GBM or randomForest or XGBoost) capture such
  interactions?

Comment: The question seems to be about multicollinearity, not about interactions. Nevertheless, depending on the setting and the model technique chosen, any strategy might be appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelM, Thanks, I'll check for multicollinearity among them. If multicollinearity is found they should be removed otherwise they should stay. Am I correct?

Comment: Why do you want to keep a sum of other variables in the model?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I don't, it was given prior in the data set. I just found that while doing EDA.

Comment: So then just drop the sum variable!

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try 4 cases here, 1. Keep all variables. 2. Keep only x4. 3. Keep only x1, x2, x3. 4.Create bins on x4 basing on optimal WOE and IV. Finally I'll compare all 4 models and select the one which performs best on test set. Please suggest if I should try something more.